# inexperto, principiante en C, rellenar Array con valores de un for, ¿es eso posible?

Tags: c, codeblocks

soy muy nuevo en programación, esta es mi duda tengo un array y quiero rellenarlo con valores de un for (esto es de un libro de Anaya) No me lo he inventado yo, el caso es que me debería dar una salida del 0 al 9 o eso dice el libro, pero me da números aleatorios, quiero saber si esa salida es correcta o si hay fallo en el escaso codigo. Uso codeBlock y probé el codigo con visual studio 2022 y decía que el array no estaba inicializado. Gracias.

```
 #include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

int numero[10];
int celda;

for(celda = 0; celda < 10; celda++){
    printf("\n numero: %i", numero[celda]);
}

return 0;
```

}

[image: Salida de codeblocks]

Comment: Y que valores esperas que tengan los elementos de `numero` si nunca les asignaste nada? Yo supongo que en el libro te saltaste la parte en la que con un `for` **llenan** el array. (Que seria algo como: `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {numbero[i] = i;}`)

Comment: Has reservado memoria para el array pero sus elementos no yienen valor, por ello es que al imprimir su valor te aparecen números aleatorios que en realidad es basura que hay en el array. Antes de imprimir trata de hacer `numero[celda] = celda`

Comment: Puede que me vaya un poco del tema pero, ¿qué son los números que ya hay en la array? Entendería que si está vacío mostrara null o algo por el estilo. ¿Por qué en algunos hay un 0 y en otros un 660416?

Comment: @Tupi C no inicializa valores.. los numeros que ves, es lo que habia en la memoria que uso para crear el array...

Comment: Ah, ¿así que eso es lo que se había guardado antes, en algún momento, en la memoria? Muchas gracias por explicarlo.

Comment: Me parece que deberíamos cerrar esta pregunta. Ya he visto varias en las que el problema es que no inicializan las variables. Quizá se pueda considerar duplicado.

Comment: @Tupi C es un lenguaje que te da un control casi total sobre tu programa. Al declarar una variable, se reservará memoria para ella. Si no la defines o asignas, al leerla verás basura. Es como si compraras una casa y el anterior dueño te la vendiera sin llevarse sus pertenencias. **Las cosas simplemente no pasan solas.**

Comment: Pablochaches y Christian tienen razón ese era el problema, pero el libro sigue en sus trece, ya he aprendido dos cosas nuevas vuestras respuestas y que el libro no vale gran cosa. Gracias a TODOS TODOS

Answer (score 1):

Todo tu código está bien, el error que tienes es que no defines qué es lo que se va a guardar en el arreglo, es decir, no le das ningún valor a cada espacio del arreglo, a lo que se guardará dentro de él. Te dejo la solución:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(void)
    {

        int numero[10];
        int celda;

        for(celda = 0; celda < 10; celda++)
        {
            numero[celda] = celda; //esta linea define lo que se guardará dentro del arreglo
            printf("\n numero: %i", numero[celda]);// es
        }

        return 0;
    }
```